# A new xml file in drawable_hdpi

Tags: android

I want to create one new xml file in the drawable_hdpi folder, but the new file doesn't appears in the drawable_hdpi folder, it appears in the layout folder. Can you tell me why?

In SDK 1.6 it is OK, but in SDK 2.2 it is not.

edit:for example  in the app res/drawable_hdpi  choice the  drawable_hdpi  folder,then right-hand button create new android xml as foo.xml,but the xml is created at the layout_hdpi folder
not at the  rawable_hdpi  folder

Comment: And why would one place an xml file in drawable to begin with?

Comment: @Ed to create custom backgrounds, for example.

Comment: please explain a little more what you mean by "appears in the layout folder". A file is a file. It will be in the folder you created the file in...

Comment: why cannot manually create the xml file in drawable, i mean go to your project location click res folder and click drawable_hdpi folder, there you create a file and name it as foo.xml and now in eclipse refresh your project , so you can able to see the created file in drawable_hdpi folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to create a new "Android XML" file in Eclipse by right-clicking on your drawable_hdpi folder.  I am able to duplicate the problem you are having.  The dialog that pops up when you try to do this can dictate where the file gets created based on various setting within.

I tried to embed and image here to show you but SO wouldn't let me.  Sorry.

The radio buttons will change the folder list beneath the "Available Qualifiers" list will change depending on which button you select.  For whatever reason, there is no radio button for drawable.  If you try to edit the folder by hand, your radio button selection disappears and the finish button disables, so you can't even force it to do what you want.

Really you should just copy an xml file similar to what you want to your drawable_hdpi folder manually outside of eclipse.  Afterwards, just do a refresh on your res folder in Eclipse and the file will show up there.  Then you should be able to edit it within Eclipse.

Hope that helps,
Craig

Comment: yes,you are right,but have other method to do it ,instead of copy an xml file similar to what you want to your drawable_hdpi folder manually outside of eclipse.?in the early sdk,we can not do it by copying

Comment: @pengwang, what do you mean you cannot do it by copying?  I mean that in Explorer or Finder, simply copy an xml file into the appropriate drawable folder.  Remember that Eclipse is simply showing you the folder structure where your project is.  You could copy or move files manually with Explorer or Finder.  You would just need to have Eclipse refresh its project view for the folders you modified.  Am I missing something?

Comment: yes,i know,i only want to know if there is a method not need copy a xml file to  the drawable_hdpi? in the early sdk,there is the method,why google  cancel the method?